# Accessing path from different package

Tags: java, file

I am trying to access a file from a different package from my program but I keep getting errors. Below is a code snippet from a method that returns a string which will be the file path. I have tried looking at previous posts with similar problems but could not find the solution. What am I doing wrong in this part of the code?

P.S. Info.IN is the name of the file that I am trying to access.

```
    URL main = Pong.class.getResource("Info.IN");
    if (!"file".equalsIgnoreCase(main.getProtocol()))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Main class is not stored in a file.");
    File path = new File(main.getPath());
     return inputResult;
```

Comment: What is inputResult? You are returning it but I don't see you assigning a value to it.

Comment: inputResult is a String form of the path. (inputResult = "" + path)

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? Please add the errors and stack traces to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't think you need this:

```
if (!"file".equalsIgnoreCase(main.getProtocol()))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Main class is not stored in a file.");
```

Try using this to get the file:

```
File path = new File(Pong.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Info.IN").toURI());
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer so I can get credit. Thanks!